# alpakka kafka auto offset reset config latest does not read messages in test case

Tags: java, playframework, apache-kafka-streams, alpakka

I have a java play application that leverages akka streams to read from kafka and output to a websocket.  my application creates a kafka source using the following:

```
Consumer.plainSource(getKafkaConsumerSettings(groupId),Subscriptions.topics(kafkaTopic))
            .map(consumerRecord -> consumerRecord.value())
```

where getKafkaConsumerSettings is the below:

```
ConsumerSettings.create(this.actorSystem, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonHelper.deserializer())
            .withBootstrapServers(this.bootstrapServers)
            .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest")
            .withGroupId(groupId);
```

I then create a Flow from the source and return it to the websocket and when I run the application I can publish messages to kafka and correctly receive all messages sent after the websocket was created.

The issue I am facing is when I run this in a test case my source will not ever emit messages.  I am able to get test cases to work if I update the auto offset reset config to be "earliest" but this is not a good solution as I would like to actually test with cases where new subscibers only see messages after they subscribed.

```
ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create();

    KafkaContainer kafka = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1"));
    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    void testProduce4Valid2Invalid() {
        kafka.start();
        toTest = new KafkaService(
            topic,
            kafka.getBootstrapServers(),
            actorSystem,
            Materializer.createMaterializer(actorSystem),
            "latest"
        );

        KafkaProducer<String, JsonNode> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(
            ImmutableMap.of(
                ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafka.getBootstrapServers(),
                ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString()
            ),
            new StringSerializer(),
            new JsonSerdes<>(JsonNode.class).serializer()
        );
        
        var nodes = toTest.getKafkaStream(groupId)
            .take(1)
            .toMat(Sink.seq(), Consumer::createDrainingControl)
            .run(actorSystem)
            .streamCompletion()
            .toCompletableFuture();

        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, "key", event1));
        assertThat(nodes).asList().containsExactlyInAnyOrder(event1);
    }
```

I am clearly sending the messages after the source has been materialized and thus would expect this to receive messages.  The other pieces of code I have is running the source in the flow I send to the websocket I use

`.runWith(BroadcastHub.of(JsonNode.class), this.materializer);`
to have all connections share the same source.

How can I setup the tests to work with auto offset rest as latest?